# How to click a <img> tag to expand a 'tree view' using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

This is the tag where I want to perform my click operation on. The element is getting located successfully, click() event is also accepted but **no action is getting performed.**

```
<img class="pointer" id="id53" src="/images/tree/elbow-minus.gif" alt="collapse not last" onclick="$(this)[0].src='/images/ajax-indicator.gif';var wcall=wicketAjaxGet('wicket/page?1-1.IBehaviorListener.0-dashboardBody-columns-0-gadgets-1-body-content-treeTable-form-rows-4-expandLink',function() { }.bind(this),function() { }.bind(this), function() {return Wicket.$('id53') != null;}.bind(this));;return !wcall;">
```

Code:

```
link_xpath = "//a[contains(text(),'git')]//parent::*/img"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(link_xpath).click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you have provided it's a `<img>` tag and the element is a dynamic element. So to click on the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.pointer[src='/images/tree/elbow-minus.gif']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@class='pointer' and @src='/images/tree/elbow-minus.gif']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```